# Django 1.11 - child template not inheriting from parent

Tags: django, django-templates, chart.js

I've read through similar stackoverflow problems and checked that I wasn't making the same mistake. I don't think this is an issue with URLs or Views as the Django-debug-toolbar shows that it's picking up the parent template, but the child template isn't extending that.

I have the following project structure:

```
project
    templates
        base.html
        index.html

    apps
        charts
            templates
                chart_base.html
                charts.html
```

> project/templates/base.html

```
<body>
    {% block wrapper %}
        <div id="wrap">
    {% endblock %}

    <div class="container" id="container-main">
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            {% block footer %}
            {% endblock %}
        </container>
    </footer>

    ....(scripts)....

    {% block extrajs %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>
```

> project/apps/charts/templates/chart_base.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<!-- chartjs container -->
    <div class='container'>
        <!-- charts.js code -->
        {% block chart %}
        {% endblock chart %}
        <!-- / charts.js code -->
    </div>
<!-- /chartjs container -->

    {% include 'base/js.html' %}

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      {% block jquery %}{% endblock %}
    })
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

> project/apps/charts/templates/charts.html

```
{% extends 'chart_base.html' %}

<!-- charts.html jquery -->
    <script>
    {% block jquery %}

    var labels = []
    var defaultData = []
    var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,

        success: function(data){
            labels = data.labels
            defaultData = data.default
            setChart()
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })

    function setChart(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: defaultData,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                }
            })
    }

    {% endblock %}
</script>

{% block chart %}

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock chart %}
```

> project/apps/charts/views.py

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'chart_base.html')
```

The HTML source of the resultant page shows that chart_base.html is rendered properly, but without the charts.html bit.

> 127.0.0.1:8000/results/

```
<div class="container" id="container-main">

  <!-- chartjs container -->
    <div class="container">
    <!-- charts.js code -->


    <!-- / charts.js code -->
    </div>
  <!-- /chartjs container -->
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should be using `charts.html`, not `chart_base.html` (which it extends).

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'chart.html')
```

You could use `TemplateView` instead of `View`:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'chart.html'
```

In your `charts.html` the comment and `<script>` tag are not in any block. That means that they won't be included in the rendered template, so you can remove them.

```
{% extends 'chart_base.html' %}

<!-- charts.html jquery -->
    <script>
    {% block jquery %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't resolved it... I've changed the code to `{% extends 'chart_base.html' %} /n {% block chart %} /n <p>chart</p> /n {% endblock %}` and still nothing. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just noticed - you're using the wrong template in your view

Comment: The issue was that I was using `chart_base.html` and not `chat.html`. It works without wrapping the script in blocks though - I was working off this example - https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Django-Chart.js/tree/master/src/templates

Comment: I was confused because the comment and script tag *are* outside of the block, so will never be used. I see now that the rest of the code is inside `{% block jquery %}`, so it will be used now that  you are using the correct template in your view.

Answer (score 1):

In your `base.html` you have a typo. You are closing the `<div>` with a `<container>` tag.

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        {% block footer %}
        {% endblock %}
    </container>
</footer>
```

It should be:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        {% block footer %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</footer>
```

Also wrap `charts.html` in a block so it can be included anywhere.